# Problem with compiling Tezos binaries in Bash-Script

Tags: setup

I follow the following commands in order to install Tezos.

```
  sudo apt-get update \
&& sudo apt-get upgrade \
&& sudo apt install -y rsync git m4 build-essential patch unzip bubblewrap wget pkg-config libgmp-dev libev-dev libhidapi-dev ntp rng-tools\
&& echo "HRNGDEVICE=/dev/urandom" | sudo tee -a /etc/default/rng-tools \
&& /etc/init.d/rng-tools start \
&& wget https://github.com/ocaml/opam/releases/download/2.0.5/opam-2.0.5-x86_64-linux \
&& sudo cp opam-2.0.5-x86_64-linux /usr/local/bin/opam \
&& sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/opam \
&& git clone https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos.git \
&& cd tezos \
&& git checkout carthagenet \
&& opam init --bare \
&& opam switch create tezos ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1 \
&& eval $(opam env) \
&& make build-deps \
&& eval $(opam env) \
&& make \
&& ~/tezos/tezos-node identity generate
```

I have also tried other recipes from the Tezos website or medium articles. When I enter the commands in bash one after another, everything works fine. However, for my research I need to automatically set up larger numbers of nodes from scratch, so I need a fully automatic setup. When I execute a single bash script containing all the above commands, the `make` command fails. All steps before seem to succeed. When I continue with `make` manually after the script aborts, everything works as expected. Moreover, when I execute `eval $(opam env) && cd tezos && make` via ssh, all seems to be fine, however, at a later stage, when I run the sandboxed client, I cannot connect to the sandboxed nodes. When I run `make` from the terminal before, the sandboxed stuff works out nicely.

Please see below the terminal output before the script fails to execute the `make` command. All has been repeatedly tested on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 where only docker has been installed.

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Terminal output]

Comment: You are aware that 'carthagenet' is the testing network, right?

Comment: Yes, ultimately I need an automatic setup of private testnets for my experiments. I have also tried with alphanet before, with the same results.

Comment: This command `opam switch create tezos ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1`, I've never used when compiling tezos. You might also want to try `make build-deps && eval $(opam env) && make` as a separate one-liner, as that is the typical "rebuild" instruction for new versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Unfortunately, also skipping the switch command did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inserting `export PATH=/home/ubuntu/tezos/_opam/bin/:$PATH` right inbetween `eval $(opam env)` and `make`, the issue could be resolved. It seems that in an interactive shell session, the environment is set automatically while it needs to be exported manually within a bash script.